# Derivation of Foucault pendulum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, oscillators

[image]
Let us define our usual Cartesian coordinates ($x'$,$y'$,$z'$), and let the origin of our coordinate system correspond to the equilibrium position of the mass. If the pendulum cable is deflected from the downward vertical by a small angle $\theta $ then it is easily seen that $x'\sim l\,\theta$, $y'\sim l\,\theta$, and $z'\sim l\,\theta^{\,2}$.

I do not understand how $x'\sim l\,\theta$, and $y'\sim l\,\theta$.

To set a [Foucault pendulum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foucault_pendulum) into motion, do I have to deflect it in a North-East or South West or South East or North West direction, such that I have equal deflections in the $x$ and $y$ directions?

PS : $y'$ is the east-west direction, $x'$ is towards north-south.

Comment: Aren't those arrived at by using the linear approximations to $x'=l\sin\theta$ and such? I suspect so, but I'm making some assumptions as to what $l$ is, which you don't describe.

Answer (score 1):

No, $\sim$ only means "proportional to". I.e., there are constants $c_x$, $c_y$ with $x'\approx c_x l \theta$ and $y' \approx c_y l \theta$ (with approximation of second order in $\theta$). It may be that one of the constants is zero.

In the case of Foucault's pendulum $c_x$ and $c_y$ are actually not really constants but slowly time-variable. They modulate the oscillation of the pendulum with the period given at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foucault_pendulum.